# Using Pivot table in pandas to add Column B Values for the same names in Column A

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 1 |
| First | 2 |
| Second | 3 |

This is a table I have in my Dataframe df , I need to use pivot table to get the following

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| First | 3 |
| Second | 4 |

Comment: you want `groupby` not pivot  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: I tried doing it using this df1 = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['sum']) , but then my data only contains the values of column B added together.

Comment: Nevermind. It was indexing when trying to convert into excel that caused that issue. Thank you